# Integrate does not converge but NIntegrate does

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a problem with Mathematica 13.0. The function f(z) does not converge in the range [zcut, 1] analytically but it does work with NIntegrate for fixed values of rho and s, where zcut = 1 - 2*s/(1 - ρ). Anybody knows how to compute the integral analytically?

The two parameters rho and s are real numbers between 0<s<1 && 0<rho <0.1 && 0<s+rho<1.

```
f = -((1 - 2*s + s^2 - ρ)^2/(-1 + s)^2)^(3/2) - ((1 - 2*s + s^2 - ρ)^2/(-1 + s)^2)^(3/2)*ρ + (12*z*ρ*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ))/(-1 + s) - 
 (3*Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - ρ)^2/(-1 + s)^2]*ρ*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ))/(-1 + s) + 
 (3*z^2*Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - ρ)^2/(-1 + s)^2]*ρ*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ))/(-1 + s) + (12*z*ρ^2*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ))/(-1 + s) + 
 (6*z*ρ*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ)^2)/(-1 + s)^2 - (z*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ)^3)/(-1 + s)^3 - (z*ρ*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ)^3)/(-1 + s)^3 - 
 (3*z*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ)^4)/(4*(-1 + s)^4) - (3*Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - ρ)^2/(-1 + s)^2]*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ)*
   (1 - 4*s + 6*s^2 - 4*s^3 + s^4 + ρ^2))/(8*(-1 + s)^3) - 
 (3*z^2*Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - ρ)^2/(-1 + s)^2]*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + ρ)*(1 - 4*s + 6*s^2 - 4*s^3 + s^4 + ρ^2))/(8*(-1 + s)^3) + 
 (24*z*ρ*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ]))/(-1 + z^2) + (24*z*ρ^2*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ]))/
  (-1 + z^2) - (24*z*ρ*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2)/(-1 + z^2)^2 - 
 (8*z*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^3)/(-1 + z^2)^3 - (8*z*ρ*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^3)/
  (-1 + z^2)^3 + (12*z*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^4)/(-1 + z^2)^4 - 
 (12*ρ*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])*Sqrt[-ρ + (-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2/(-1 + z^2)^2])/
  (-1 + z^2) + (12*z^2*ρ*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])*
   Sqrt[-ρ + (-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2/(-1 + z^2)^2])/(-1 + z^2) + 
 8*(-ρ + (-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2/(-1 + z^2)^2)^(3/2) + 
 8*ρ*(-ρ + (-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2/(-1 + z^2)^2)^(3/2) - 
 (3*(1 - s - z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])*Sqrt[-ρ + (-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2/(-1 + z^2)^2]*
   (-ρ + (2*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2)/(-1 + z^2)^2))/(1 - z^2) - 
 (3*z^2*(1 - s - z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])*Sqrt[-ρ + (-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2/(-1 + z^2)^2]*
   (-ρ + (2*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2)/(-1 + z^2)^2))/(1 - z^2) - 
 15*ρ^2*ArcTanh[(-1 + 2*s - s^2 - ρ)/((-1 + s)*Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - ρ)^2/(-1 + s)^2])] + 
 9*z^2*ρ^2*ArcTanh[(-1 + 2*s - s^2 - ρ)/((-1 + s)*Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - ρ)^2/(-1 + s)^2])] + 
 15*ρ^2*ArcTanh[(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])/
    ((-1 + z^2)*Sqrt[-ρ + (-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2/(-1 + z^2)^2])] - 
 9*z^2*ρ^2*ArcTanh[(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])/
    ((-1 + z^2)*Sqrt[-ρ + (-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*ρ])^2/(-1 + z^2)^2])];
```

An example for the numerical integration would be:

```
zcut = 1 - 2*s/(1 - ρ);
NIntegrate[
 f*UnitStep[z - zcut]/. ρ -> 1.15^2/4.6^2 /. 
  s -> 0.4, {z, 0, 1}]
```

Result: 0.0714195

Comment: Can you give the values for $\rho$ and $\sigma$ for which `NIntegrate` works? Also the proper syntax is NOT `f(z)=` but rather `f[z_]:=`

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just another question. Are we integrating `f` or `f*UnitStep[z - zcut]`???

Comment: As stated in the question z is integrated in the range [zcut, 1], hence f*Unitstep[z -zcut]

Comment: @NeAr Could you explain what this function `f` for?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think `Integrate` claims divergence due to the expansion given by `Series` at `z=1`. Which might indicate a bug, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

This is also an extended comment. I am hoping that the author of the OP will find it useful.

Note also, that the approach taken here is similar in spirit to the previous one by @lxndr
. Since `Integrate` is listable and Mathematica refuses for her own reasons to do the full thing at once, let's try to help her as much as possible.

I am using `f` directly taken from the OP. Also the lower cut-off is given by

```
zcut = 1 - 2*s/(1 - ρ);
```

Ι am sitting on `$Version`

> `"13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`

---

1. We split the integrand

   `flist = List @@ Expand[f];`

and we check how many terms we got

```
flist // Length
```

> `270`

Nice!

Now, we invoke our friend `Rubi`

```
Get["Rubi`"]
```

and for completeness

```
$RubiVersion
```

> ```
> "Rubi 4.16.1.0"
> ```

Before we proceed we break down the general idea. From those 270 terms in the expanded version of the integrand, Mathematica does some of them without any complaints, while she finds it difficult to deal with some others. For instance for the 21$^{st}$ term she complains

```
Integrate[flist[[21]], {z, zcut, 1}] // FullSimplify
```

[image: complain1]

Her issues are close to 1. So, we can subtract something from said value, say 1-a with $a>0$, integrate to the new point, and do the `Series` expansion as $a \rightarrow 0$. In other words,

```
Assuming[a > 0, Integrate[flist[[21]], {z, zcut, 1 - a}]] // 
   Series[#, {a, 0, 0}] & // Normal // FullSimplify
```

[image: res1prem]

We can check the validity of this approach with a term for which she does not complain at all. Let's do the first term

```
Integrate[flist[[1]], {z, zcut, 1}] // FullSimplify
Assuming[a > 0, Integrate[flist[[1]], {z, zcut, 1 - a}]] // 
   Series[#, {a, 0, 0}] & // Normal // FullSimplify
```

both of the above return

[image: res2prem]

Now, I am not sure if this approach agrees with the taste of the author of the OP, as it has not been addressed yet. I hope that they don't have any issues with this.

Edited bit 1:

How to go about it in general?
Well, let's do an easy case. The first two terms. `Integrate` separately, do the `Series` around `a` goes to `0` and then sum the individual contributions.

For a list that looks like this

```
rubilist = 
 Table[Assuming[a > 0, Int[flist[[ii]], {z, zcut, 1 - a}]] // 
   FullSimplify, {ii, 1, 2}]
```

[image: bountystuff1]

you can execute

```
FullSimplify[Total@Series[rubilist, {a, 0, 0}] // Normal]
```

that gives

[image: bountystuff2]

End of edited bit 1.

---

**WHY SHOULD WE USE RUBI?**

Well, we do have 270 terms to consider. The following, hopefully, is a persuasive result.

```
listtestmma = 
 RepeatedTiming[
  Table[Assuming[a > 0, Integrate[flist[[ii]], {z, zcut, 1 - a}]] // 
     FullSimplify, {ii, 1, 21}];]
```

[image: rubivsmma1]

```
 listtestrubi = 
 RepeatedTiming[
  Table[Assuming[a > 0, Int[flist[[ii]], {z, zcut, 1 - a}]] // 
     FullSimplify, {ii, 1, 21}];]
```

[image: rubivsmma2]

So, it is clear how much better `Rubi` does in this particular example.

As a matter of fact, I checked the first 150 terms on my laptop

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Table[Assuming[a > 0, Int[flist[[ii]], {z, zcut, 1 - a}]] // 
    FullSimplify, {ii, 1, 150}];]
rubilist = 
  Table[Assuming[a > 0, Int[flist[[ii]], {z, zcut, 1 - a}]] // 
    FullSimplify, {ii, 1, 150}];
```

[image: final1]

Practical note: if you follow this path, please take into consideration that `Rubi` does not fancy `UnitStep` as she does not have any rules for it, and that's why I re-wrote the integrand in the way I did.

I understand that this is not the end of the computation, but I am hoping that this is useful suggestion.

---

**Edit 2: pushing `Rubi` and the suggested method or how I learned to stop worrying and took care of the first 177 terms.**

This leaves 93 terms to be considered.

Note that the next term can also be evaluated. I just had to drop `FullSimplify` as it was taking forever. I used `// TrigExpand // Simplify`. Have to revisit.

```
rubilist1 = 
  Table[Assuming[a > 0, Int[flist[[ii]], {z, zcut, 1 - a}]] // 
    FullSimplify, {ii, 1, 177}];
```

Time to apply the proposed computational method to the above list

```
Simplify[
 PowerExpand[Factor[Total@Series[rubilist1, {a, 0, 0}] // Normal]]]
```

returns

[image: bountyres01]

For completeness, I am providing the results of the individual integrations

```
rubilist1 // TableForm
```

[image: 1to177results]

**Edit 3: `FullSimplify` is `Listable` and maybe we can attempt to do so at the level of the integrand. 206 out of the 270 terms down. 64 to go**

`FullSimplify` was mentioned but never addressed. It is not that difficult to be performed at the level of the **integrand** to try and simplify as much as possible before feeding something into `Integrate`

```
RepeatedTiming[
 TrigToExp@
   FullSimplify[Factor[flist[[1 ;; Length@flist]]], 
    0 < s < 1 && 0 < \[Rho] < 0.1];]
```

> `{1.04319, Null}`

```
fsflist = 
  TrigToExp@
   FullSimplify[Factor[flist[[1 ;; Length@flist]]], 
    0 < s < 1 && 0 < \[Rho] < 0.1];
```

Then we can sum all the elements as

```
Total@fsflist
```

and hope that this integral will finish. However, this took more time than I could spare both using `Rubi` and without it - I have some upcoming deadlines, sorry.

So, this takes me back to the cheeky approach of computing the integration of each individual term in the list where we performed `FullSimplify`

In other words we perform

```
rubilistfs = 
  Table[Assuming[a > 0, Int[fsflist[[ii]], {z, zcut, 1 - a}]], {ii, 1,
     206}];
```

it takes a bit but it finishes. And this is as far as I have checked.

Answer (score 3):

Just a hint, not a full solution: It seems to me that you need to simplify f so that some non converging terms cancel.

Try `flist = List @@ Expand[f];`.

Entry flist[[17]] is the first one that does not integrate, its value is `(12 z)/(-1 + z^2)^4`. For z->1 this gets infinite. I think that's the reason for Integrate[] to fail.

Since numerical integration converges there should be a counterterm canceling this. Simplify[] or FullSimplify[] should find and eliminate these, at least if the right assumptions are given.
Unfortunately this simplification seems to be very time consuming - I stopped after some time of calculation.

Answer (score 3):

To analyze function $F(\rho,s)\int _{zcut}^1fdz$ we need to know is this function analytical on $0<\rho <1$ and $0<s<1$. For this we map interval $(zcut,1)$ to unit interval with using variable $y=(z-zcut)/(1-zcut)$. Let us define function `g=f/.{z -> y (1 - zcut) + zcut, s -> (1 - zcut) (1 - \[Rho])/2}` then function `F` can be defined in numerical form as follows

```
FF[x1_?NumericQ, 
  x2_?NumericQ] := (1 - x2) NIntegrate[
   g /. {\[Rho] -> x1, zcut -> x2}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Let check that `FF` is limited at the origin

```
FF[$MachineEpsilon, $MachineEpsilon]

Out[]= 0.132812
```

With this definition we can plot function `FF`

```
Plot3D[FF[x1, x2], {x1, $MachineEpsilon, 1/2}, {x2, $MachineEpsilon, 
  1/2}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "zcut", ""}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing",
  MeshStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Function `F` looks like analytical around origin, and therefore we have a chance to get some expression to describe `F`. To do this we expand function `g` in series and define several functions

```
ff = Normal[Series[g, {zcut, 0, 3}]];
coef=CoefficientList[ff, zcut];
F0[x1_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[coef[[1]] /. \[Rho] -> x1, {y, 0, 1}]

data0 = Table[{x1, F0[x1]}, {x1, $MachineEpsilon, 1/2, .01}];

nlm0 = NonlinearModelFit[data0, 
  a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4 + h x^5, {a, b, c, d, e, h}, x];
 F1[x1_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[coef[[2]] /. \[Rho] -> x1, {y, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4] // Quiet

data1 = Table[{x1, F1[x1]}, {x1, $MachineEpsilon, 1/2, .01}];
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[data1, 
  a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4 + h x^5, {a, b, c, d, e, h}, x];

F2[x1_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[coef[[3]] /. \[Rho] -> x1, {y, 0, 1}];
    
data2 = Table[{x1, F2[x1]}, {x1, $MachineEpsilon, 1/2, .01}];

nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data2, 
  a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4 + h x^5, {a, b, c, d, e, h}, x];

F3[x1_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[coef[[4]] /. \[Rho] -> x1, {y, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4] // Quiet

data3 = Table[{x1, F3[x1]}, {x1, $MachineEpsilon, 1/2, .01}];
nlm3 = NonlinearModelFit[data3, 
  a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4 + h x^5, {a, b, c, d, e, h}, x];
```

Finally we define analytical function described `F` with using series

```
fan[x_, x2_] := (1 - x2) (nlm0[x] + x2 nlm1[x] + x2^2 nlm2[x] + 
    x2^3 nlm3[x])
```

Visualization

```
Plot3D[fan[x1, x2], {x1, 0, 1/2}, {x2, 0, 
  1/2}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "zcut", ""}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing",
  MeshStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Note, that `fan` looks very similar to function `FF` shown in Figure 1. We can express it in variables $\rho ,s$ and plot with using restrictions $\rho+s<1$

```
fff=((1 - x2) (nlm0[x] + x2 nlm1[x] + x2^2 nlm2[x] + 
      x2^3 nlm3[x]) // Normal) /. {x2 -> 1 - 2*s/(1 - \[Rho]), 
  x -> \[Rho]}



(* Out[]= 1/(
     1 - \[Rho]) 2 s (0.132915 - 0.85593 \[Rho] + 2.10123 \[Rho]^2 - 
       2.01754 \[Rho]^3 - 0.195384 \[Rho]^4 + 
       1.13491 \[Rho]^5 + (1 - (2 s)/(1 - \[Rho]))^2 (-0.1946 + 
          0.0518435 \[Rho] + 5.52769 \[Rho]^2 - 20.5944 \[Rho]^3 + 
          29.2689 \[Rho]^4 - 15.0774 \[Rho]^5) + (1 - (2 s)/(
          1 - \[Rho])) (-0.0472983 + 1.05398 \[Rho] - 4.94447 \[Rho]^2 + 
          9.34393 \[Rho]^3 - 7.08349 \[Rho]^4 + 1.14942 \[Rho]^5) + (1 - (
          2 s)/(1 - \[Rho]))^3 (0.0307526 + 0.112229 \[Rho] - 
          6.21303 \[Rho]^2 + 30.6017 \[Rho]^3 - 55.892 \[Rho]^4 + 
          35.9643 \[Rho]^5))*)


Plot3D[ If[\[Rho] + s < 1, fff, Nothing], {\[Rho], 0, 1/2}, {s, 0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "s", ""}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
 MeshStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Update 1. We can improve code with using more series coefficient and make `Do` loop

```
g = -((1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho])^2/(-1 + s)^2)^(3/
        2) - ((1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho])^2/(-1 + s)^2)^(3/
        2)*\[Rho] + (12*z*\[Rho]*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + \[Rho]))/(-1 + 
       s) - (3*Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho])^2/(-1 + 
            s)^2]*\[Rho]*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + \[Rho]))/(-1 + s) + (3*z^2*
       Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho])^2/(-1 + s)^2]*\[Rho]*(1 - 2*s + 
         s^2 + \[Rho]))/(-1 + s) + (12*
       z*\[Rho]^2*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + \[Rho]))/(-1 + s) + (6*
       z*\[Rho]*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + \[Rho])^2)/(-1 + 
        s)^2 - (z*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + \[Rho])^3)/(-1 + 
        s)^3 - (z*\[Rho]*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + \[Rho])^3)/(-1 + s)^3 - (3*
       z*(1 - 2*s + s^2 + \[Rho])^4)/(4*(-1 + s)^4) - (3*
       Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho])^2/(-1 + s)^2]*(1 - 2*s + 
         s^2 + \[Rho])*(1 - 4*s + 6*s^2 - 4*s^3 + 
         s^4 + \[Rho]^2))/(8*(-1 + s)^3) - (3*z^2*
       Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho])^2/(-1 + s)^2]*(1 - 2*s + 
         s^2 + \[Rho])*(1 - 4*s + 6*s^2 - 4*s^3 + 
         s^4 + \[Rho]^2))/(8*(-1 + s)^3) + (24*
       z*\[Rho]*(-1 + s + 
         z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]]))/(-1 + z^2) + (24*
       z*\[Rho]^2*(-1 + s + 
         z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]]))/(-1 + z^2) - (24*
       z*\[Rho]*(-1 + s + 
          z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2)/(-1 + 
        z^2)^2 - (8*
       z*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^3)/(-1 +
         z^2)^3 - (8*
       z*\[Rho]*(-1 + s + 
          z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^3)/(-1 + 
        z^2)^3 + (12*
       z*(-1 + s + z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^4)/(-1 +
         z^2)^4 - (12*\[Rho]*(-1 + s + 
         z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])*
       Sqrt[-\[Rho] + (-1 + s + 
             z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2/(-1 + 
             z^2)^2])/(-1 + z^2) + (12*
       z^2*\[Rho]*(-1 + s + 
         z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])*
       Sqrt[-\[Rho] + (-1 + s + 
             z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2/(-1 + 
             z^2)^2])/(-1 + z^2) + 
    8*(-\[Rho] + (-1 + s + 
            z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2/(-1 + 
            z^2)^2)^(3/2) + 
    8*\[Rho]*(-\[Rho] + (-1 + s + 
            z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2/(-1 + 
            z^2)^2)^(3/
        2) - (3*(1 - s - z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])*
       Sqrt[-\[Rho] + (-1 + s + 
             z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2/(-1 + 
             z^2)^2]*(-\[Rho] + (2*(-1 + s + 
               z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2)/(-1 + 
             z^2)^2))/(1 - z^2) - (3*
       z^2*(1 - s - z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])*
       Sqrt[-\[Rho] + (-1 + s + 
             z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2/(-1 + 
             z^2)^2]*(-\[Rho] + (2*(-1 + s + 
               z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2)/(-1 + 
             z^2)^2))/(1 - z^2) - 
    15*\[Rho]^2*
     ArcTanh[(-1 + 2*s - s^2 - \[Rho])/((-1 + s)*
         Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho])^2/(-1 + s)^2])] + 
    9*z^2*\[Rho]^2*
     ArcTanh[(-1 + 2*s - s^2 - \[Rho])/((-1 + s)*
         Sqrt[(1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho])^2/(-1 + s)^2])] + 
    15*\[Rho]^2*
     ArcTanh[(-1 + s + 
         z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])/((-1 + z^2)*
         Sqrt[-\[Rho] + (-1 + s + 
               z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2/(-1 + 
               z^2)^2])] - 
    9*z^2*\[Rho]^2*
     ArcTanh[(-1 + s + 
         z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])/((-1 + z^2)*
         Sqrt[-\[Rho] + (-1 + s + 
               z*Sqrt[1 - 2*s + s^2 + (-1 + z^2)*\[Rho]])^2/(-1 + 
               z^2)^2])] /. {z -> y (1 - zcut) + zcut, 
    s -> (1 - zcut) (1 - \[Rho])/2};

ff = Normal[Series[g, {zcut, 0, 4}]];

coef = CoefficientList[ff, zcut]; nn = Length[coef];

Do[data[i] = 
  Table[{x1, 
    NIntegrate[coef[[i]] /. \[Rho] -> x1, {y, 0, 1}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4] // 
     Quiet}, {x1, $MachineEpsilon, 1/2, .01}]; 
 nlm[i] = NonlinearModelFit[data[i], 
   a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4 + h x^5, {a, b, c, d, e, h}, 
   x];, {i, nn}]

fan[x_, x2_] := (1 - x2) Sum[nlm[n][x] x2^(n - 1), {n, 1, nn}]
fff = ((1 - x2) Sum[nlm[n][x] x2^(n - 1), {n, 1, nn}] // 
    Normal);

fff //. {x2 -> 1 - 2*s/(1 - \[Rho]), x -> \[Rho]}

(*Out[]= 1/(
 1 - \[Rho]) 2 s (0.132915 - 0.85593 \[Rho] + 2.10123 \[Rho]^2 - 
   2.01754 \[Rho]^3 - 0.195384 \[Rho]^4 + 
   1.13491 \[Rho]^5 + (1 - (2 s)/(1 - \[Rho]))^4 (0.0542876 - 
      0.331013 \[Rho] + 6.4239 \[Rho]^2 - 35.6162 \[Rho]^3 + 
      73.6482 \[Rho]^4 - 52.5108 \[Rho]^5) + (1 - (2 s)/(
      1 - \[Rho]))^2 (-0.1946 + 0.0518435 \[Rho] + 5.52769 \[Rho]^2 - 
      20.5944 \[Rho]^3 + 29.2689 \[Rho]^4 - 15.0774 \[Rho]^5) + (1 - (
      2 s)/(1 - \[Rho])) (-0.0472983 + 1.05398 \[Rho] - 
      4.94447 \[Rho]^2 + 9.34393 \[Rho]^3 - 7.08349 \[Rho]^4 + 
      1.14942 \[Rho]^5) + (1 - (2 s)/(1 - \[Rho]))^3 (0.0307526 + 
      0.112229 \[Rho] - 6.21303 \[Rho]^2 + 30.6017 \[Rho]^3 - 
      55.892 \[Rho]^4 + 35.9643 \[Rho]^5))*)
```

We can plot final result to observe improvement around line $\rho +s=1$

```
Plot3D[ If[\[Rho] + s < 1, 
  fff //. {x2 -> 1 - 2*s/(1 - \[Rho]), x -> \[Rho]}, 
  Nothing], {\[Rho], 0, 1/2}, {s, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "s", ""}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
 MeshStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 4]

But direct computation with `FF` shows different picture

```
Plot3D[ If[x + s < 1, FF[x, 1 - 2*s/(1 - x)], 
  Nothing], {x, $MachineEpsilon, 1/2}, {s, $MachineEpsilon, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "s", ""}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
 MeshStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 5]

It means that there is different criterium `1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho] >= 0` follows from `g` definition. With this criterium we have picture very similar as above

```
Plot3D[ If[1 - 2*s + s^2 - \[Rho] >= 0, 
  fff //. {x2 -> 1 - 2*s/(1 - \[Rho]), x -> \[Rho]}, 
  Nothing], {\[Rho], 0, 1/2}, {s, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "s", ""}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
 MeshStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 150]
```

[image: Figure 6]